# Array allocation speed issue

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am currently writing a Monte Carlo code whose volume is fluctuating. I divide my simulate cell, a cube, into many smaller cubes for algorithm speed reasons. However as the volume fluctuates, the number of these smaller cubes also fluctuates. Therefore, I have been reallocating my arrays that contain info on these smaller cubes as necessary:

```
 !.....................................................................................!
  ! want to assign each atom to appropriate cell
  ! generate list of atoms in each cell for GONET algorithm
  ! arrays are allocated and deallocated in this routine. 
  !......................................................................................!
  subroutine indiv_cell_lists_alloc(r)
    implicit none
    double precision :: r(3,param%np)
    integer :: i,icell,size_cl
    integer :: temp_num(0:listvar%ncellT-1) !...listvar%ncellT is total number of cells.
    integer :: temp_cell(param%np)


    temp_num(:) = 0

    !--- param%np is total number of particles in simulation
    do i = 1 ,param%np

       !--- based off coordinates, finds what cell particle i is in
       icell = cell(r(1,i),r(2,i),r(3,i))

       temp_cell(i) = icell
       temp_num(icell) = temp_num(icell) + 1     

       !--- keep particles current cell
       atom(i)%cell = icell 
       atom(i)%loc  = temp_num(icell)       
    enddo


    !--- listvar%cl is an array. listvar%cl(i) contains info for cell i
    !--- listvar%cl(i)%cmem(:) is an array containing the particles that are in the ith cell
    !--- deallocate cell member lists
    !--- subtract one since array is 0:ncellT-1, where ncellT is total number of cells
    size_cl = size(listvar%cl)-1
    do i = 0, size_cl
       deallocate(listvar%cl(i)%cmem)
    enddo

    !--- deallocate cell list
    deallocate(listvar%cl)

    !--- allocate new celllist
    allocate(listvar%cl(0:listvar%ncellT-1))

    !--- allocate new arrays
    do i = 0, listvar%ncellT-1
       !--- allocate new array based off new size
       allocate(listvar%cl(i)%cmem(temp_num(i)))

       !--- number of molecules in cell 
       listvar%cl(i)%num = temp_num(i)
    enddo



    do i= 1,param%np
       !--- get cell for particle
       icell = temp_cell(i)

       !--- place particles in cell
       listvar%cl(icell)%cmem((atom(i)%loc)) = i
    enddo


  end subroutine indiv_cell_lists_alloc
```

Now the reason I am making sure that these arrays are only as big as they need to be, is that eventually these arrays will be exported to a Xeon Phi coprocessor. Due to the reduced memory there, I think that just allocating a large amount of memory and forgetting about it would lead to bad performance. However in serial execution, this subroutine is taking up ~70% of my run time.

Do you have any suggestions on how I could accomplish this reallocation more efficiently, or any suggestions about other methods I could use?

Comment: You are paying a huge cost to continually modify physically resident data structures, but a virtual data structure would work just as well. Why not modify your algorithm input to operate on sub-sections of the single master array? The choice of sub-array indices can remain dynamic. Perhaps I don't understand your hardware limitations properly?

Comment: I don't think I understood you properly. Could you reexplain, perhaps with an example?

Comment: I think right now you are doing something like this: For simplicity, imagine you have a 1D array of size N. You create 10 sub-arrays, each of size N/10, and allocate their contents based on the original array. Then you run your monte carlo 10 times, on each of these new arrays...

Comment: ...Instead of doing this, why not pass a reference to the original master array into the monte carlo algorithm, but also pass a list of indices representing sub-array edges? Then the code that does the work runs a loop X=10 times, once per "virtual" sub-array, using the relevant indices for each loop. If N=100, first time round, you only operate on elements 1-10. Second time round, elements 11-20. And so on. This is logically equivalent to what you are doing, but involves no allocation of new arrays.

Comment: Ok I think I am starting to understand. However, how would you know the size of the initial master array? Would you just guess this one and give it some padding? Also, do you think this method would suffer on a xeon phi coprocessor due to the random memory access?

Comment: @user3225087 You can start out with an initial array size, and keep on doubling it when you hit its boundaries for the master array. See amortized time: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/363/notes/06A_Amortizing.html